# How to pass JVM arguments and script argument using GroovyShell?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, groovy

So I have a Groovy script:

```
// TestScript.groovy
println args
```

Then in a Gradle task I have

```
test {
  String profile = System.getenv("spring.profiles.active")
  jvmArgs '-Dspring.profiles.active=$profile" // THIS DOES NOT WORK! :(

  doLast {
    new GroovyShell().run(file('package.TestScript.groovy'))
  }
}
```

What I need to do is two things:

a) Pass into `TestScript.groovy` program arguments so it will print out the `args` array

b) Pass to JVM the Spring Boot profile i.e. `spring.profiles.active=dev`

Any suggestions?

Note, I'm using Groovy 2.4.3 and referring to this documentation: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html

I tried the following which was unsuccessful:

```
doLast {
  Binding b = new Binding();
  b.setVariable('spring.profiles.active', $profile)
  new GroovyShell(b).run(file('package.TestScript.groovy'))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists_groovy/tree/master/stack_overflow_64084870) ...

If we have a script that writes arguments to a file:

```
// TestScript.groovy

try {
    new File("out.txt").withWriter { writer ->
        args.each { arg ->
            writer.write("TRACER arg : ${arg}\n")
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    new File("error.txt").withWriter { writer ->
        writer.write("TRACER caught exception ${ex.message}\n")
    }
}
```

then we can test it with this Gradle task:

```
test {
    doLast {
        def profile = project["spring.profiles.active"]

        def script = new File("${projectDir}/TestScript.groovy")
        def args = ["exampleArgVal1", "exampleArgVal2", profile]

        new GroovyShell().run(script, args)
    }
}
```

Note that parameters are passed to Gradle like so:

```
gradle clean test -Pspring.profiles.active=TEST_PROFILE
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I love that you linked to a working solution! The problem now is that the script that runs this doesn't run the test cases. The way that works is TestSuite actually has a runner that calls @SpringBootTest and collates the results. The thing here is that TestSuite.groovy now can't find any of it's imports. I tried to resolve this by adding the classpaths to the ClassLoader to no avail. How can I get GroovyShell to inherit the classpaths of the test task?

Comment: I tried an alternative way, which I have an outstanding [question for here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084870/how-to-pass-jvm-arguments-and-script-argument-using-groovyshell) that might provide more insight into the issue.

Comment: @groovydude I think your question (re: "the problem now") is beyond the scope of the original question. Note that the link in the 2nd comment points to this question (!).

Comment: @ Michael Easter 
You are right. I have marked the question as accepted. I will create a new question. I was hoping you had a quick solution on how to add the proper class paths in. I tried with GroovyClassLoader, but that didn't work.